# What does the ▲ operation do here? 15 ▲ 13 = 14, so 18 ▲ 12 =?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

I am trying to answer this puzzle - which of the five potential answers is correct, and why?

> I. 15 ▲ 13 = 14
> II. 10 ▲ 14 = 12
> III. 25 ▲ 5 = 15
> IV. 18 ▲ 12 = ?
>
> - A) 20
> - B) 18
> - C) 16
> - D) 15
> - E) 13

This test comes from the Metropol iq1 book

Comment: it seems like that this puzzle comes from elsewhere. please provide the source. unattributed work may get downvoted or even closed. happy puzzling ;)

Comment: this puzzle my friend created and sent to me

Comment: 'Your friend' appears to be creating and sending you quite a few of these... (There were more of these yesterday...) Is there a reason why you cannot ask this friend for the same assistance you're asking of us? Do they mind you asking all of them on Puzzling?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton So if you suspect, as I assume you do, that this puzzle comes from some sort of test that OP is trying to cheat on or something of the kind, _why did you answer it_?

Comment: Actually, my friend didn't send them. I'm preparing for the exam and asking questions I don't know from testbook. I couldn't find any other guy or website to ask these questions.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan seeing the OP's confession I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The answer is d) 15 because it is the midpoint between 18 and 12. +3 and -3 respectively.